# Yet another "Mac cannot find USB serial port" post

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, osx

I have read about every post about people having issues with their Arduinos on Macs. I have a 100% authentic Arduino UNO, that I cannot by any circumstance manage to connect to my late 2009 iMac with macOS Sierra 10.12.2.

I tried just about anything from disabling Apple FTDI drivers, installing FTDIUSBSerialDriver, D2XX drivers and even the CH34X drivers (for knockoffs). NOTHING works.

Not even setting boot arguments, not disabling default extensions/drivers, not removing extensions/drivers.

I am completely stuck, and no guide has ever worked. I've tried rebooting numerous times, but still no luck. The only port available in the Port menu is the Bluetooth Incoming port.

Does anyone have any tips or hints? I am on the verge of doing a complete reinstallation of my computer just to have all drivers back to default.

Comment: What does `dmesg` tell you while you plug it in?

Comment: Alot of "AMFI: allowing exception handler for 'polard' (3658) because the process is unsigned." (I guess polard is my Polar heart rate monitor). Other messages: IO80211Interface::updateReport _peerManager is missing. That is basically it.

Comment: A little research and I'm not so sure polard is the heard rate monitor at all. For every time I connect the Arduino, a new line with this message shows up.

Comment: Does the same USB port work for other USB devices? Try another port? Can you test whether another computer sees your Arduino? Substitute a different USB cable?

Comment: An actual Uno does not require drivers on OSX as support for CDC/ACM is built in.  Fair warning: answers which ignore this and propose installing FTDI, CH340, CP210x, etc drivers **will be severely down-voted**.  This question is about an Arduino Uno; it is not about random other boards with different details.

Comment: @JRobert I've tried all ports on my iMac (4) plus the 2 on the keyboard. Not one of them is working with the Arduino. All of them are working with other devices. The Arduino does not work with my girlfriends MacBook Pro (OS X El Capitan 10.11.5), but it did work on my dads MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra 10.12.2). My dad only had to install the FTDI drivers to get it to work.

Comment: It sounds a lot like the Arduino or the cable, just by the fact that it fails on at least two machine. I'm surprised, though, that you needed install any drivers. Macs have understodd FTDI out of the box since at least OS 10.6.8; It's just the alternative USB <-> serial chips that have needed any additional drivers.

Comment: Thanks @JRobert. Are there some way to reset the whole Arduino to factory settings?

Comment: Just by powering it off. There aren't any arduino settings relevant to how it appears to a computer. That's built in to the auxilliary 8u2 or 16u2 processors' firmware and not configurable any way that I've ever heard of.